# Location manager stops working after reboot swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, locationmanager

I am trying to use location manager in my application. I set the code as I saw in many posts and examples and everything is working fine, and I get the location manager to show the current location as set in the simulator. I then change the location in the simulator and my app gets the new location.

I then reboot my machine, and restart my application, but the location manager stops working. I tried to change the code from using addObserver() to using didUpdateLocations, and sometimes I manage to restart the location manager to work. But when I reboot the machine it stops working again. I tried resetting the simulator and authorizing again the app to get location updates, but with no success. In all cases my app prints that it has authorization to get location update but it does not work. I also tried cleaning the app and rebuilding it, but with no success. 
Below are the 2 versions of the code I use.

**CODE with addObserver**

```
class TViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var myLocation: CLLocation?
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    mapView!.settings.myLocationButton = true
}

// get updates of myLocation
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?,
                                     ofObject object: AnyObject?,
                                              change: [String : AnyObject]?,
                                              context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
    myLocation = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? CLLocation
    print("in newlocation =  \(myLocation)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        print("in myLocation is authorized")
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView!.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    }
}
}
```

**CODE with didUpdateLocations**

```
extension TViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        print("in myLocation extension is authorized")
        isLocationAvailable = true
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            myLocation = locations.first
            print("in newlocation extension =  \(myLocation)")
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: myLocation!.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
}

class TViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

var myLocation: CLLocation?
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    mapView!.settings.myLocationButton = true
}
```

Comment: that is a "normal" behaviour of the simulator. Try changing it to Apple and to your custom location again. I do this all the time just to make it work.

Comment: Use the delegate method.  Don't use KVO, and yes you need to restart location simulation each time the simulator is restarted.

Comment: Changing to "Apple" and back yo "Custom Location" did the trick. Just a note that this happened only on reboot of the computer - quitting the simulator and restarting it did not cause the location to stop.

Comment: @Paulw, can you explain why not to use the KVO?

Comment: KVO is a generic low-level objective C approach. The delegate is designed to deliver location updates. It supports location update deferral and the delivery of multiple location updates at a single call.

Comment: @Paulw,  Thank you